# Dove si usa 'accorsato'?

Tags: word-usage, regional

Ho da tempo una curiosità.

Io sono di Napoli, e a Napoli è comune usare il termine' accorsato', ad esempio "quello è un negozio accorsato" per dire che è un negozio molto frequentato, con molta clientela. Dopo il trasferimento a Roma, se lo dicevo non mi capivano, mi guardavano con gli occhi sbarrati. Per cui ho notato che si tratta di un uso regionale, per quanto sia italiano e non dialetto. Questa la definizione data dal vocabolario Treccani:

> agg. [propr. part. pass. del merid. accorsare «dar corso, avviare»],
> merid. – Bene avviato, con molta clientela: un negozio, un ristorante
> a.; e, in genere, assai frequentato: cinema accorsato.

Quindi chiedo a chi di voi è italiano, o conosce bene l'italiano, se questo termine gli è familiare, o sa in quali regioni si usa.

Comment: Da romano, temo che ti avrei guardato un po' strano anch'io... Ma sono contento di aver imparato una parola nuova. :)

Comment: Grazie della risposta. In effetti, io credevo di essere normale, invece mi guardavano strano. E non è l'unica parola per cui mi guardavano strano a Roma :-)

Comment: Onestamente, non avevo mai sentito il termine "accorsato"; né in Lombardia (Milano), dove sono nato e cresciuto, né in Puglia (Lecce), dove vivo da alcuni anni.

Comment: Io sono veneto e non l'avevo mai sentito. Infatti, probabilmente l'avrei frainteso e interpretato come un negozio in cui ti mettono fretta...
Nota che anche il Treccani precisa che è un termine di uso meridionale.

Comment: Grazie delle risposte. Vedo che in Puglia pare che non si senta, infatti ho sempre avuto il dubbio che fosse prettamente napoletano, anche se non dialettale, come ci sono altri termini non dialettali ma credo usati quasi solo a Napoli, tipo 'lo scatolo' o 'broche'. Forse diventati un po' desueti.